# C# Checking SmtpAddress from all accounts in Outlook

Tags: c#, email, outlook

I am trying to send an email through C# and Outlook. It sometimes did work and not it never does the Code which rashes is this one

```
            //Look for our account in the Outlook
            foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Account account in accounts)
            {
                if (account.SmtpAddress.Equals(sFromAddress, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
                {
                    //Use it
                    acc = account;
                    break;
                }
            }
```

At the If clause it is always false, even though it has to be correct. I checked it manually. It seems like the **account** from **accounts** is not able to be created...

The Stacktrace of the Error:

```
bei ConsoleApp2.Program.sendEmailViaOutlook(String sFromAddress, String sToAddress, String sCc, String sSubject, String sBody, BodyType bodyType, List`1 arrAttachments, String sBcc) in C:\Users\z003th6d\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\ConsoleApp2\ConsoleApp2\Program.cs:Zeile 252.
```

And the Exception message:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Der Objektverweis wurde nicht auf eine Objektinstanz festgelegt.
   bei ConsoleApp2.Program.sendEmailViaOutlook(String sFromAddress, String sToAddress, String sCc, String sSubject, String sBody, BodyType bodyType, List`1 arrAttachments, String sBcc) in C:\Users\z003th6d\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\ConsoleApp2\ConsoleApp2\Program.cs:Zeile 252.
```

For further Code here is the gist link: https://gist.github.com/1524045patrick/400b3676c0e95627334a09ba9cc39c2e

Comment: Are you sure?  Have you debugged it and observed the values of `account.SmtpAddress` and `sFromAddress`?

Comment: Yes I have the error is. "System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException" in ConsoleApp2.exe

Comment: Well why didn't you include that in your question to begin with?  How could you *not* view that as necessary information for us?  Also, please include more details about the exception: what is the message?  any error codes associated with it?

Comment: @rory.ap because the Error Message is in German, but sorry I will add it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the account does not have an SMTP address, `SmtpAddress` returns an empty string.

I'd recommend checking the [Account.AccountType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Outlook-VBA/articles/account-accounttype-property-outlook) property which returns a constant in the `OlAccountType` enumeration that indicates the type of the `Account`.

In case of `olExchange` account you need to get an SMTP address in the following way:

```
    Outlook.AddressEntry sender =
        account.CurrentUser.AddressEntry;
    if (sender != null)
    {
        //Now we have an AddressEntry representing the Sender
        if (sender.AddressEntryUserType ==
            Outlook.OlAddressEntryUserType.
            olExchangeUserAddressEntry
            || sender.AddressEntryUserType ==
            Outlook.OlAddressEntryUserType.
            olExchangeRemoteUserAddressEntry)
        {
            //Use the ExchangeUser object PrimarySMTPAddress
            Outlook.ExchangeUser exchUser =
                sender.GetExchangeUser();
            if (exchUser != null)
            {
                return exchUser.PrimarySmtpAddress;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return sender.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty(
                PR_SMTP_ADDRESS) as string;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
```